# disabled multiple check box when i have select drop down list

Tags: jquery

I am new for  disabled multiple check box when i have select drop down list  .using java script.

Here code source i have that are not better approach all fields disabled.

```
function select(Seect)
{
  if(datatype=="varchar")
  {

     document.getElementById("field").disabled=true;
  }
}
```

**strong text**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the demo code for disable all checkbox of the page using jquery. try below code...

```
function select(Seect)
{    
   if(<your condition>)
   {    
      $('input[type="checkbox"]').attr("disabled","disabled");
   }
}
```

let me know if you have any issue....